# Why is this boolean parameter for Jenkins / Gradle (defined in groovy) not working?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jenkins-job-dsl

I have this Jenkins job defined in groovy and I would like to tick the "Make gradlew executable" box.

```
steps {
    gradle {
        executable(true)
        tasks("""forbiddenApisMain
jar""")
    }
}
```

[image]

According to https://readthedocs.org/projects/jenkins-job-builder/downloads/pdf/stable/ (page 102), I need to set executable to true
However I get this error:

`ERROR: (Build.groovy, line 576) No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.GradleContext.executable() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Boolean) values: [true]`. I don't get the error if I remove `executable(true)`). Any idea? I checked and I have the latest plugin

Comment: Try `makeExecutable(true)` instead of `executable(true)`

Comment: this worked, thanks @NoamHelmer (I was on jobs-dsl, not job-builder)